# RadDateTimePicker is not working with IE 8, 10

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik, raddatepicker

I have RadDateTimePicker in my ASP.net web page.
I noticed that it is not working properly on IE 8 and 10. After selecting the date or the time, the control shows another date (wrong year).
I also tried the  Demo page

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

It contains the same issue.
Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I had selected an invalid timezone in my local machine.
After I selected a valid time zone the control worked fine on IE.
It looks like the control rely on client's machine to calculate time and date (in case we are using IE)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the demo link using both IE8 and IE10 in my VMs downloaded from IE's virtualization tools (https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) and I didn't experience the issue.

It might be that your ASP.NET web page is in quirks mode and as per Telerik's documentation, the quirks mode rendering engine for IE is not supported:

http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tech-sheets/browser-support

Ensure to set a valid doctype like the one for HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```